# Automatic Browse Service.svc file in iis

Tags: iis

I have created a **WCF service** which i have hosted in **IIS**. When I start the service in **IIS**, the Service do not started until I browse my Service.svc file.

Application pool gets recycled after a specific interval, then when the Service is restarted I again need to go and browse the **Service.svc** file.

I have set this Service as Default bt it does not work and results the same.

Is there any way to automatic browse my **Service.svc** file when the Service is started or restarted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general annoyance with IIS. It launches worker processes to perform website processing which don't (always) start until the website has been requested. The workaround I've used in the past is to hit a page outside of my web application to launch the IIS worker process so it is available when I need it. Be careful though there are some nuances to the app pools that can make this more complicated than it needs to be.